# Rails randomically changes language on production (Globalize3 and Digital Ocean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize3, digital-ocean

I'm building a rails project and everything works fine, but for some reason, when I deploy it at my Digital Ocean VM, the language of the website randomically changes while navigating.

Here's the website link.
http://www.adimaxpet.com.br/

Is there any code snippet I could post to help you guys understand it better?

I'm using rails 3.2.13, globalize3 and activeadmin-globalize3.

---

I've set the locale at application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = 'pt-BR'
config.i18n.available_locales = [:"pt-BR", :en, :es ]
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

Comment: Can you show us where you set the locale ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem isn't Globalize3 as I noticed that it shows the locale parameter after I choose to change the locale but it looses this parameter after clicking in other links. However, the menus seems to work which seems strange to me.

I followed [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n-revised) to configure I18n. Maybe it helps you.

I'm Brazilian too. Feel free to get my contact through my SO profile.

I hope it helps.